# PSI change listener

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I need a listener that can notify if PsiElement is not vaild. PsiTreeChangeListener seems not fit for this. Is there any other listener that can tell this. Or i have to create a listener ? How to create this listener?

Comment: I'm not sure it's possible and/or necessary. Can you please tell us what you want to achieve?

Comment: In the starting i got all the required psiElements, but if in between someone comment or remove or move any psiElement, then that psiElement will become invalid or null. so i wanted to know at that time and according to that i want to update my list of all psiElements. i was thinking of implementing observer pattern in this case but i need listener for that. so if any psiElement become invalid from that list then list will get to know and remove that element from that list. I am not getting how should i implement this listener.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **SmartPsiElementPointer** class to create and maintain list of psi elements.

**SmartPsiElementPointer** is a pointer to a **PsiElement** which doesn't become invalid even if the psi element it points to was deleted. In that case it's **getElement()** method will simply return *null*. You can detect and handle this.

To wrap an element into **SmartPsiElementPointer** you can use the following code:

```
SmartPointerManager.getInstance(element.getProject()).createSmartPsiElementPointer(element);
```